# Getting Wrong date format as result in R

Tags: r, date

I am trying to separate a date from a column in a database, but the result date format is not proper.

column data = `"24-01-2021 19:15"`

Code used:

```r
database_1$date <- format(as.Date(database_1$start_time), "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Result: `20-01-0024`

Expected result: `24-01-2021`

Comment: Try `as.Date(start_time, "%d-%m-%Y")`

Answer (score 1):

Update:
I just realized the expected output:
just add `format("%d.%m.%Y")` to the code:

```
as.Date(dmy_hm(column_date)) %>% 
  format("%d.%m.%Y")
```

```
[1] "24.01.2021"
```

With lubridate package you can:

1. With `dmy_hm` you read in the character `column_date` to date format
2. Then you can add `as.Date`

```
library(lubridate)

column_date <- "24-01-2021 19:15"

as.Date(dmy_hm(column_date))
```

```
[1] "2021-01-24"
```